# I cannot seem to be able to use CreateFormFile and CreateFormField to create a new request

Tags: http, go

I am trying to construct a request with the multipart.CreateFormFile and multipart.CreateFormField, but I am not having any success on transferring the data to its destination.

I want to send a form post to a client and the client will do some pre-processing of the data and then send it to its final destination at the server. It should be noted, I am only have problems when a file is being transferred, a normal application/x-www-form-urlencoded I can get it to work fine.

So here is my scenario. Someone submits a form with a file to /post, the /post route will then take the form data and use multipart.CreateFormFile and multipart.CreateFormField to make a new http.newRequest.

Here is my code:

```
    http.HandleFunc("/post", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

        r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)

        file, header, _ := r.FormFile("file")
        
        b := bytes.Buffer{}
        we := multipart.NewWriter(&b)

        var fw io.Writer
        
        defer we.Close()
        
        fw, err := we.CreateFormFile("file", header.Filename) //create the new file field 

        _, err = io.Copy(fw, file) //copy the file to the new file field
        
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error with copy")
        }

        for key, r0 := range r.Form { //this creates and copies the form values to the new created form
            if fw, err = we.CreateFormField(key); err != nil {
                return
            }

            _, err = io.Copy(fw, strings.NewReader(r0[0])) //copies field data to new form field

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error with copy fields")
            }           
        }

        req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:3000/newpost", &b) //make new request from buffer

        CheckError(err, "error with post form req")
        req.Header.Set("Content-Type", we.FormDataContentType()) //set content type

        resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req) //send request and get response

        CheckError(err, "error with post form resp")

        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
    })
```

This is stumping me because I am finding minimal explanation on what I am trying to achieve, or I am missing something fundamental.

So in summary, I want to create a new Form with a file to send in an http.NewRequest through POST. If I pass in http.Request.Form to the NewRequest it sends only the form values and not the form file.

Comment: Call [we.Close()](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#Writer.Close) before creating the new request.  The deferred call to we.Close() executes after the request is done. This is not a problem, but you can simplify the code for writing fields by calling [we.WriteField(key, r0[0\])](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#Writer.WriteField).

Comment: wow, thank you for pointing that out. I cant believe it was something so simple that I missed that I have been bagging my head against the wall trying to figure it out! I appreciate it, it seems to be working how I was wanting it to. I also simplified with WriteField. Thank you for the advice.